# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tty' in '/workspace/node_modules/pace/node_modules/charm'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

After trying to build my frontend project with ng build I get this error message:

> ERROR in ./node_modules/pace/node_modules/charm/index.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve 'tty' in
>   '/workspace/node_modules/pace/node_modules/charm'

Trying `npm install tty --save` or `npm install pace --save`  does not resolve the issue.

node version is : v11.10.0
angular version : 7.0.0

Comment: Angular's latest development version is 8. 11 is not possible.
Also it seems the difference between AngularJS and Angular might not be clear to you.
Please overhaul your question an correct the details so we are able to help you.

Comment: it's node version sorry

Comment: A ok. Now the information makes more sense. I also removed AngularJS tag with an edit (might not yet be approved).

Comment: what is your angular version?
have you tried cleaning your `node_modules` folder?

Please edit your question to reflect the correct versions of angular and node.

Comment: angular 7.0.0 ...

Comment: @Arikael  Yes I did clean `node_modules `

Comment: resolved by modifyng index.js in node_modules/pace/node_modules/charm

Have to change `var tty = require('tty');`
 with `var tty = require('tty-browserify');`

Comment: just to be sure:
You are installing this `pace`? -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/pace

if yes, this hasn't been updated for 7 years. I wouldn't use a package this old.
For what do you need `pace`in a angular application (I assume a web application)?

Answer (score -6):

resolved by modifyng index.js in node_modules/pace/node_modules/charm

Have to change `var tty = require('tty');`
 with `var tty = require('tty-browserify');`

Comment: you should never modify any files in `node_modules` since it will get overwritten everytime you update the package or any time another developer installs packages.

Comment: in case you clean yeah, but in case of jut update, no problem

Comment: if the package would get updated (which is highly unlikely) it would be overwritten.

In my eyes this is a "solution" destined to fail sometime in the future.